# How to include browsing and web search in a prompt with few shot examples for ChatGPT?

Tags: chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

I'm including few shot examples for a custom GPT with `Web Browsing` enabled. I would like ChatGPT to browse all user provided links before answering. What keywords should I include in the few shot example to demonstrate for ChatGPT it should browse?

```
USER:
"""
Summarize the history of Rolling Stones! All background information is available at:
 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones and
 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mick_Jagger
"""

ASSISTANT:
"""
[BROWSE INSTRUCTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones)
[BROWSE INSTRUCTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mick_Jagger)
Based on the links provided, the story of Rolling Stones started [...]
"""
```

My quesiton is what keywords I should use in the place of `[BROWSE INSTRUCTION]` in the example for the custon GPT?